# Serialize/De-serialize objects via HTTP, Ruby (no ROR)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, json, serialization

There is already similar question to this but I am not satisfied with answers since I am trying to do something more complex.

I have web service which provides list/single objects. Objects are Users, Categories, etc. Here is example of object:

```
<UserObject name="foo" description="bar" category=<Category name="cat1" description="bar"> locations=[<Location id=1>, <Location id=2>] >
```

In other words objects are somewhat complex and can be arrays of those objects. I am looking for a way to:

- Serialize these object to JSON or Hash string
- Send them over HTTP
- Deserialize them to OpenStruct objects

Service that is serializing objects is not ROR.
App that is receiving and deserializing objects is ROR.

There must be some generic way to do this, I tried using `to_json` and `JSON.parse` but it only de-serializes object to one level. So for example above I would get:

```
<OpenStruct name="foo" description="bar" category="{\"name\"... JSON STRING}" locations="JSON STRING">
```

Instead of JSON STRINGs I would like to get objects inside object as it was in original.

Ruby: 1.9.3

Thanks

Comment: @ChrisCashwell Marshalling and sending over HTTP sounds like bad idea? Maybe I am wrong, but encoding could give me issues.

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at the [oj](https://github.com/ohler55/oj) gem. It allows you to serialize and deserialize ruby objects to and from json. It also has the benefit of being very fast.

Comment: Excellent gem, tried it! But does it convert to open struct? It will not work unless I have my domain classes present. So when I send them over http I do not have access to them, only to copy them over but that is nightmare waiting to happen. I am reading to docs to see if I can force open struct.

Comment: I'm not sure about open struct, but it works with regular ruby classes. If anything you could have really basic classes with simple `attr_accessor`s in them. Be careful about security though because an attacker could potentially insert any arbitrary ruby object via json.

Comment: Thanks @josh-voigts Oj gem is excellent, solution to my problem bellow.

Answer (score 0):

After looking into [oj](https://github.com/ohler55/oj) gem and contacting it's creator Peter Ohler, who was very nice and helped, I was able to get desired effect.

```
require 'oj'

# user instance is nested instance
json_string = Oj.dump user

# send over http
# de-serialize without domain classes (classes created by Oj gem)
user = Oj.load(json_string, { :auto_define => true })
```

Thanks to @josh-voigts for letting me know about the gem.